# How to skip a mandatory field in custom layout when you create a new record

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, master-detail

**Background**;

I have created a custom object A which has a Master-Detail relationship field to a Parent object (Let's say it's field F).
I also created a custom layout for the object A.

**Problem**

When I create a new record of object A, I need to set some value for field F since it's a mandatory field. (Please see the image attached.)

**Expected Result**

I want user to skip inputting the field F and want to fill the value from back end(for example, using Trigger.) since it's troublesome for user.

**What I want to ask**

How can I achieve the **Expected Result** above ?

Thank you so much in advance !!!

[image]

Comment: Master-Details Relationship links two object bit tighter. You must specify Parent while creating child records if it is coupled with M-D relationship. Please go through this module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/data_modeling/object_relationships for better understanding. You can try using Lookup relationship if it is fine for your business need.

Comment: thank you for your reply !!
Yea, I know about the Master-Details Relationship and Lookup relationship is not enough since the behavior needs to be controlled by the parent (like deleting, access permission, etc...)

Comment: I wonder if I can hide the field and when the data comes to backend, and fill the field by backend.

Comment: you cannot avoid fact that master-detail relationship is mandatory. you can try applying some workaround like creating a placeholder parent record and populate that by default. once the data available in backend update the child records to re-parent to new record. Make sure to select "Allow reparenting" when you created the Master-Detail relationship field on the Child/Detail object

Comment: default value sounds good! but do you have any idea how to do this part in detail ?

>(creating a placeholder parent record and populate that by default)


thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: If you have object A and Object B, lets say B is the child and A the parent. If you create the record from the related list, the master will be already pre-populated, if you need any other field, I would question why do you need the field to exist in the child object if the value already exists in the parent? Do you actually need that new field?